# Wildcards and OR clause in App Script (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-api

Having some issues with my App Script code when trying to sync a Google Calendar to a Google Sheet.
I've written an if statement that posts calendar events to a specific sheet within my Google Spreadsheet based on the description of the event. The if statement does work however its not very user friendly as it has to be that specific word. I'd like to add some OR clauses and some wildcards so that if the event booker types in caps, no caps etc / doesn't type it in exactly it will still recognise the event.

I was thinking something like this - however it doesn't work and returns no error message (thanks JavaScript, haha!):

//DOES NOT WORK BUT NO ERROR MESSAGE :(

```
 if (description.includes("ASM Salford" || "Salford" || "ASM Sal" || "ASM SALFORD")) {
  asmsalfordsheet.getRange(i+12,1).setValue(startTime);
  asmsalfordsheet.getRange(i+12,2).setValue(title);
}
```

//DOES WORK BUT IS TOO SPECIFIC - DOESN'T GIVE USER MUCH FLEXIBILITY:

```
 if (description.includes("ASM Salford")) {
  asmsalfordsheet.getRange(i+12,1).setValue(startTime);
  asmsalfordsheet.getRange(i+12,2).setValue(title);
}
```

/DOES NOT WORK BUT NO ERROR MESSAGE:

```
 if (description.includes("ASM Salford" || "Salford")) {
  asmsalfordsheet.getRange(i+12,1).setValue(startTime);
  asmsalfordsheet.getRange(i+12,2).setValue(title);
}
```

// ALSO DOES NOT WORK BUT NO ERROR MESSAGE:

```
 if (description.includes("*ASM*")) {
  asmsalfordsheet.getRange(i+12,1).setValue(startTime);
  asmsalfordsheet.getRange(i+12,2).setValue(title);
}
```

Comment: First your `"ASM Salford" || "Salford" || "ASM Sal" || "ASM SALFORD"` is not a string but `false`.  `||` is logical or so you are coding `string1 or string2` which would yield `false`.  So your `description.includes(false)` would yield `false`.

Comment: @TheWizEd Non-empty strings are truthy, so it's logically `true`. But `||` doesn't convert its result to a boolean, it returns the first truthy value left-to-right. So the value is `"ASM Salford"`

Comment: `description.includes("XXX") || description.incluides("YYY") || description.includes("ZZZ") ...`

Comment: You can use something like `["ASM Salford", "Salford", "ASM Sal" , "ASM SALFORD"].some((v) => description.includes(v))`

Comment: By the way, you don't need `"ASM Salford"` because, if it is included, it will be matched by either `"Salford"` or `"ASM Sal"`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a regular expression.

```
if (description.match(/(ASM )?(Salford|SALFORD)|ASM Sal/))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who answered! I ended up doing the below in the end and it worked:

```
  if (description.toLowerCase().includes('ASM'.toLowerCase()) && (description.toLowerCase().includes('SAL'.toLowerCase()))) {
// do this
}
```